# Aurelia TypeScript application not working in internet explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, typescript, aurelia, ecmascript-2016

We have created single page application using aurelia framework. We are using `es7 decorators` in aurelia application. The application works fine in chrome and firefox, but does not working in IE 9,10. But it will works fine in IE 11.

The browser console it shows an error `"Unhandled promise rejectionError"`.

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: You need to polyfill older browsers as the Readme for the repo you are referencing mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from [the documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/app-configuration-and-startup) itself inside of the App Configuration and Startup page.

> Aurelia was originally designed for Evergreen Browsers. This includes
>   Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Safari 8. However, we also support IE9 and
>   above through the use of additional polyfills. To support these
>   earlier browsers, you need to add an additional polyfill for
>   MutationObservers. This can be achieved by a jspm install of
>   github:polymer/mutationobservers. Then change your index.html startup
>   code as follows:
>
> #### Polyfill configuration
>
> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>My App</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
>     <script src="config.js"></script>
>     <script>
>       SystemJS.import('core-js').then(function() {
>         return SystemJS.import('polymer/mutationobservers');
>       }).then(function() {
>         SystemJS.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
>       });
>     </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. It Worked